# Check if a file extension does not exist in a directory using Go

Tags: go

I am trying to check if a directory does not have a file with a ".rpm" extension. I will not know what the filename is beforehand and each directory will have multiple files.

Here is my code:

```
import {
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
}

func main() {
    dirname := "." + string(filepath.Separator)

    d, err := os.Open(dirname)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer d.Close()

    files, err := d.Readdir(-1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Print("\n" + "Reading " + dirname)

    for _, file := range files {
        if file.Mode().IsRegular() {
            // TODO: if rpm file not present, print no rpm file found
            if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == ".rpm" {
                fmt.Println(file.Name() + "\n")
                f, err := os.Open(file.Name())
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will open any .rpm files within the current directory.

I want to check for the following: if a ".rpm" file does not exist the list of files of the current directory, then print "rpm does not exist" and os.Exit.

I've tried this code:

```
if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) != ".rpm" {
    fmt.Println("no rpm found")
}
```

and I've tried using

```
if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == ".rpm" {
    ... *code above* ...
} else {
    fmt.Println("ERR: RPM file does not exist")
}
```

I'm running into the error where if other files are present without the extension of .rpm, then it will prompt the error.

How can I go about doing this without having the filename beforehand?

Comment: Your logic is just incorrect. It should be pretty simple to fix it. Instead of returning an error as soon as you find a file that doesn't match, return a non-error as soon as you find one that does.

Answer (score 1):

Whether none of the files have `.rpm` extension cannot be told in any single iteration. You can only tell that for certain after checking all files.

So instead of trying to squeeze that into the loop, maintain a `found` variable which you may update when an `.rpm` file is found.

```
found := false // Assume false for now
for _, file := range files {
    if file.Mode().IsRegular() {
        if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == ".rpm" {
            // Process rpm file, and:
            found = true
        }
    }
}

if !found {
    fmt.Println("rpm file not found")
}
```

If you only need to process 1 `.rpm` file, then the "state" management (the `found` variable) will not be necessary. You can return if you found and processed an `.rpm` file, and if you get to the end of the loop, you'll know there wasn't any `rpm` file:

```
for _, file := range files {
    if file.Mode().IsRegular() {
        if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == ".rpm" {
            // Process rpm file, and:
            return
        }
    }
}

// We returned earlier if rpm was found, so here we know there isn't any:
fmt.Println("rpm file not found")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks so much. Originally, I tried to check for an rpm using a boolean but didn't declare the if !found statement outside of the for loop so it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...
splitted := strings.Split(file.Name(), ".")
lenSplit := len(splitted)
if lenSplit > 1 && splitted[lenSplit-1] == "rpm" {
  // file with extension
}
...
```

1. Split filename by "."
2. Go to the last string in the array of string
3. Check if the last string match "rpm"